# js validation send both massage

Tags: javascript, html

i make HTML form send parameter to JavaScript to check if the input is equal the value in array then send alert message but the problem is the function send both alerts  when the condition is true

this is my code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function test(){
            var cars=["a","b","c"];
            var c;
            var inp=document.forms["form1"]["input1"].value;

            for(c=0;c<cars.length;++c){

                if(cars[c]===inp){
                    alert("we have it");

                }else{
                    alert("we don't have ");
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="get" name="form1" onsubmit="return test()">
        <input type="text" name="input1" />
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
```

i revise both alerts   **"we have it"** AND **"we don't have "**

what is wrong with this code ??

Comment: It's in a loop, that's why you see 2 more times "we don't have"

Comment: Change `alert("we have it");` by `alert("we have it"+"because "+cars[c]+"="+inp);` and alert("we don't have "); by `alert("we don't have "+"because "+cars[c]+"<>"+inp);`, then you can see why you get  "we have it" AND "we don't have " alerts

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the logic, you need to look to see if it is there and look through all of them. You should not be alerting on every index.

```
var inStock = false;  //Use a boolean to hold state
for(c=0;c<cars.length;++c){
    if(cars[c]===inp){  //see if it matches
        inStock = true;  //if it matches set Boolean to true
        break; //exit loop (no reason to keep looking)
    }
}
if(inStock) {  //check the boolean to see if we found it
  alert("we have it");
} else {
  alert("we don't have ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add a return after the condition is met...

```
function test(){
        var cars=["a","b","c"];
        var c;
        var inp=document.forms["form1"]["input1"].value;
        for(c=0;c<cars.length;++c){
            if(cars[c]===inp){
                alert("we have it");
                return;

            }else{


                alert("we don't have ");
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: use `c`, not `a`. You will get 3 alerts. "don't", "don't", "have". Only difference with yours and OP is if you pick "b" or "a", it will not show the alerts for the following indexes.

Comment: true...using a boolean flag is the better answer